# Wildcarded search with "*" and "?" in search:search not working properly

Tags: marklogic

We need to achieve the wildcarded searches with both the characters "*" and "?" as described in

https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/guide/search-dev/wildcard

Wildcard Characters
Marklogic Server supports two wildcard characters: * and ?.

- matches zero or more non-space characters.
  ? matches exactly one non-space character.
  For example, he* will match any word starting with he, such as he, her, help, hello, helicopter, and so on. On the other hand, he? will only match three-letter words starting with he, such as hem, hen, and so on.

But we do the search as below,

```
let $options := <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">   
                  <constraint name="DocumentTitle">
                    <word type="xs:string" facet="false">
                      <element ns="http://marklogic.com/nondeliverable" name="DocumentTitle"/>
                      <search:term-option>wildcarded</search:term-option>, 
                       <search:term-option>case-insensitive</search:term-option>,
                       <search:term-option>diacritic-insensitive</search:term-option>,
                       <search:term-option>unstemmed</search:term-option>
                    </word>
                  </constraint>
                  <return-query>true</return-query>
                  <return-qtext>true</return-qtext>
                  <return-metrics>true</return-metrics>
                </options>
                
return (search:search("(DocumentTitle:(medi*ation))",$options,1,10),search:search("(DocumentTitle:(medi?ation))",$options,1,10))
```

Both the search queries are returning same count. But if we do the search

```
cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("nd:DocumentTitle"),"medi?ation",("wildcarded"))),cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("nd:DocumentTitle"),"medi*ation",("wildcarded")))
```

the count are different and returning the proper result.

How we can achieve wildcarded searches with both the characters "*" and "?" in search:search with proper result.

Answer (score 1):

`cts:search` runs filtered by default, while `search:search` runs unfiltered by default. Pass in `filtered` as option to `cts:search`, and see if that returns the same results as `search:search`.

Alternatively, you can also provide a [search-option](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/appendixa#id_77801) to make search:search behave filtered:

```
<search-option>filtered</search-option>
```

Filtering is slow by the way, and ideally you should choose index settings that make filtering unnecessary. Check if you have enabled wildcard settings.

HTH!